# Can shadow traits in mapped traits be persisted

Tags: traits, enthought

Let's consider the code

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Int, Trait, File
from traitsui.api import InstanceEditor, View, Item, HGroup, OKCancelButtons

class A(HasTraits):
    value = Int
    nature = 'Integer'

class B(HasTraits):
    value = File
    nature = 'Filename'

class Test(HasTraits):
    a = A()
    b = B()
    c = Trait(a.nature,{x.nature : x for x in [a,b]})
    view = View(
                HGroup(
                    Item('c',show_label=False),
                    Item('c_',show_label=False,
                            style='simple',
                            editor=InstanceEditor(label='...',kind='modal'))),
                buttons=OKCancelButtons           
                )

t = Test()

t.configure_traits(filename='/Volumes/FAT/Python/Tests/abc.dat',kind='modal')
```

When run, a dialog proposes to choose between an integer or a filename type of parameter, and a button labelled '...' allows to enter adequate values in a cascading dialog box. Unfortunately, the value of the edited int or filename (corresponding to the cascading dialog box and to the 'shadow' trait c_) is not saved, although the choice of 'integer' or 'filename' is.

Adding

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.trait('c_').transient = False
```

does not change anything (although t.trait('c_').transient returns True without the previous code).

Is there a way to achieve the persistence of the shadow trait?